# node, is each request and response unique or cached irrespective of url

Tags: node.js

In an app that I was working, I encountered "headers sent already error" if I test using concurrency and parallel request methods.

ultimately I resolved the problem using `!response.headersSent` but my question is why am I forced to use it? is node caching similar requests and reuses them for the next repeated call.

```
    if(request.headers.accept == "application/json") {
        if(!response.headersSent) {response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})}
        response.end(JSON.stringify({result:{authToken:data.authToken}}));
    }
```

Edit

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', server.address().address, server.address().port);
});
```

Edit 2:
Another problem is while testing using mocha, super agent and while the tests in progress if I just send another request through postman on the side, one of the tests in mocha end with a timeout error. These steps I'm taking to ensure the code is production ready for simultaneous, parallel requests? please advise on what measures I can take to ensure node/code works under stress.

Edit 3:

```
app.use(function(request, response, next){
    request.id = Math.random();
    next();
});
```

Comment: What package are you using for your HTTP? Normal node `http`?

Comment: to reproduce this problem in your apps, if you press cmd+r (keep it pressed for a continuous refresh) it will crash the node, if `!response.headersSent` is not in place - meaning node re-uses request/response objects

Comment: The error about headers already being sent is nearly always because you are not handling async operations correctly and thus your code ends up running out of sequence.  Nothing to do with caching.

Comment: Each request and response is unique.

Comment: I do pass around my request/response object but then each function call javascript creates a new stack of variables I believe, is there something that I can read to enlighten myself and handle the async operations properly

Comment: Not much we can do to help find the issue without seeing the actual code where you're passing the response around.  Likely you're trying to do something with the response in an async callback, but other code didn't wait until the async response was done before it also operated on the response.

Comment: bingo @jfriend00 your comments made me sort of look into this light and I've started to see the cause, as I'm working under a framework rules, I guess i've to make things more flexible under those rules. Now in order to completely resolve it If you can now point me to some `id` parameter that exists in request or response object that uniquely identifies the request/response object, I'd be able to nail it down. I've been outputting the whole response object but don't seem to find a unique identifiable variable in it. please advise.

Comment: @user2727195 - you could create your own middleware (just a couple lines of code) that would stamp a unique id on each request object as it comes in, but my sense is that if you're trying to use that to solve this problem, you're looking at the wrong way to solve this.  We're handicapped to offer any further help because you're not showing us the actual code where the problem is.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'd love to share it with you but I assume you may not have any idea about puremvc's proxies and mediators and that would just create some more confusion, I may not be right, they sorta of objects that live in the system (i.e. not created for each request), now my approach would be to instantiate new one for each request, and an id of a request would help, and believe me it'd work and that's how its supposed to be, I did an edit 3 in my code, but Math.random can't be 100% guaranteed to be unique each time, any suggestions on that.

Comment: @user2727195 - just use an increasing counter for a unique ID.

Comment: Awesome @jfriend00. respect.

Comment: @jfriend00 it works in parallel now, now registering a unique proxy 'ProxyName + request.id` for each request and removing it on completion. I don't need the request.headersSent check anymore either, It's awesome how you were able to solve the issue irrespective of not seeing the whole picture of the code (some limitation because of the size of the project, limitation on isolating the issue and not so much use of this framework in the nodejs world). Thanks for bearing the limitations and still helping to workout the problem. hats off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in an attempt to capture what solved this for you via all our conversation in comments, I will attempt to summarize here:

1. The message "headers sent already error" is nearly always caused by improper async handling which causes the code to call methods on the response object in a wrong sequence.  The most common case is non-async code that ends the request and then an async operation that ends some time later that then tries to use the request (but there are other ways to misuse it too).
2. Each request and response object is uniquely created at the time each individual HTTP request arrives at the node/express server.  They are not cached or reused.
3. Because of asynchronous operations in the processing of a request, there may be more than one request/response object in use at any given time.  Code that is processing these must not store these objects in any sort of single global variable because multiple ones can be in the state of processing at once.  Because node is single threaded, code will only be running on any given request at any given moment, but as soon as that code hits an async operation (and thus has nothing to do until the async operation is done), another request could start running.  So multiple requests can easily be "in flight" at the same time.
4. If you have a system where you need to keep track of multiple requests at once, you can coin a request id and attach it to each new request.  One way to do that is with a few lines of express middleware that is early in the middleware stack that just adds a unique id property to each new request.
5. One simple way of coining a unique id is to just use a monotonically increasing counter.